# optimize hevc_toolbox encoding to look like x265 encoding in ffmeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc

I am encoding videos from h264 to h265 using ffmpeg. First I used the x265 software version for a 30 sec movie clip reducing the file size from 18Mb to 2Mb and got the following still-frame result in 45 sec
[image]

Next I used the hevc_videotoolbox hardware accelerated version, first going from 18 to 1.6 Mb and the results were so poor I decided to up the bitrate to 1.5Mbit/s, thus getting a 5.7Mb file in 12 sec. However, the result is clearly inferior to the x265 version despite the almost 3x increase in filesize.

[image]

Any ideas if it is possible to improve the hevc_toolbox quality and still retain the speed advantage?

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -an -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -y test_x265.mp4 

ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -an -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -vtag hvc1 -y -b:v 1.5M test_vt.mp4
```

I am on a MB pro late 2017 version with kaby lake

Answer (score 2):

hevc_videotoolbox is hardware accelerated and because of that it will never be as efficient as x265. If you have the time I would recommend you using x265.